# Long press an element to show the black options bubble(copy,forward..) like wtsapp?

Tags: ionic-framework

Can someone point me to the right direction of how to show options(copy, forward...) when I long press an element (a message in this case) like wtsapp/FB messenger?

I don't even know what keywords should I be searching...(tried modal, popover, action sheet)

Thanks.

Update:
I understand that I should use the on-hold gesture...I am specifically looking for the black option bubble to be shown. I don't know what it is called(not modal/pop up/ action sheet/popover/alert). Thanks.

Comment: use `on-hold = "edit()"` function to show a modal box

Comment: Sorry guys I wasn't being clear enough... I understand that the gesture is "onHold", what I am looking for is the black option bubble to be shown (not action sheet, popover, modal, popup)

Like in this image: http://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/larger_wm_brw/public/field/image/2014/02/imessage_copy_iphone_5_hero.jpg?itok=bvIgFgBm

Answer (score 0):

you can use `on-hold="myFunction()"`, check the link below
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/

and then use the `$ionicActionSheet` Service to do your logic, check the link below
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicActionSheet/

Answer (score 0):

`on-hold` event is your friend : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/

I think following Codepen example would help in accomplishing what you want to do:

Actionsheet : http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/jLylA

Also, have a look this thread on Ionic Forum before you start implementing, just to avoid any similar issue, plus, this thread got some CodePen examples, that your might find useful :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/displaying-actionsheet-on-a-long-press-aka-hold-event-problem/5663

Answer (score 0):

You can implement long press with either `on-hold` and if you want to implement long press for buttons, try this directive from [this link](https://gist.github.com/Mahabali/15152feac0e35677f96b8348f2f1017f) and a note on directive can be found [here](https://mobilitysolutionsexpert.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/long-press-detection-for-ionic-angular-js-based-apps/) . You may need to use a custom action sheet ($ionicActionSheet) to implement the UIMenuController (iOS component) like feature.

```
.selectable{
-webkit-user-select: auto;
```

}

for selection and `ion-content` to  `overflow-scroll="true"`